# Locale on Debian 7 doesn't change

Tags: linux, debian, locale

So I have tried all things that I could Google up but still locale settings aren't changed (kind of, you will see what I mean).

To start off desired locale (lv_LV.UTF-8) is available on the system:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
lv_LV.utf8
POSIX
```

I have tried to set locale with `sudo update-locale lv_LV.UTF-8`

Also tried to set manually in `/etc/default/locale` and `/etc/environment` with no luck:

```
LANG=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

If i check what locale is set then I get:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

So what DOES actually work is that I get Latvian text in Gnome calendar and see entry in Region and Language settings "Latvia".
But if I try running Libre Calc then it recognizes dot as decimal separator instead of coma (which is set in Latvian locales).

So what else I can/should do to fully enable Latvian locales in Debian? Basically I need this because when I make inserts to database from PHP project it blames that e.g. '1,25' is invalid number and it should be '1.25' but on production server it accepts vice-versa: should be '1,25' and not '1.25'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of assorted things:

1. Forget about `/etc/environment` — Debian switched to using `/etc/default/locale` instead in Etch (4.0).
2. The point of `/etc/default/locale` is to make a couple of environment variables appear in a process which *initiates a user's login session.*

   Now there are several ways to log into a Debian system; to name a few:

   - Via virtual consoles — those textual screens presenting you with the `Login:` prompt you typically see on a system without the X Window system or when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> when working on an X diplay.
   - Via X Window "display manager" — that graphical thing which lets the user provide their authentication credentials and then starts the X Window server running some sort of desktop environment for them.
   - Via SSH.

   (There may be others but that's beyond the point.)

   What matters here is that creating the user's session on Linux-based systems typically goes through the so-called [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) layer, which has its configuration under `/etc/pam`.  Now if you do

   ```
   $ grep -r locale /etc/pam.d
   ```

   you'll see that the file `/etc/default/locale` is being read in a few places there.

   What I'm leading you to, is that in order to actually "see" the changed locale settings, you have to create another login session — no matter how you do it.  Say, log on another virtual console, or quit your X desktop session and log back in.
3. Since `/etc/default/locale` only sets a bunch of environment variables, *they may be overridden.*

   What I'm leading you to, if that suppose you log in on a virtual console; in the end your login shell is run and shows you its prompt.  But when the shell starts up, it reads its startup scrips.  For instance, `bash`, when running as a login shell, reads `~/.bash_profile` if that exists or `/etc/bash_profile` if the former fails.  Your local `~/.bash_profile` may containg something like

   ```
   export LANG=en_US
   ```

   …and viola — you have your environment settings overridden.

   Non-login shells also read startup scrits (`bash` reads `~/.bashrc`) and these scripts might change the environment variables as well.

   So, please double check you don't have overriddes in whatever starts your session up.  Notice that it's hard to get more precise pointers because there are many ways to get a working session on a Debian system, and the way it's being set up depends on its type.
4. If the interaction of your PHP code with your database backend depends on the active locale the PHP process sees, your project is seriously botched and you'd better concentrate on fixing it instead rather than your locale.  Otherwise this will bite you in the neck, sooner or later.

   The whole concept of locale settings exists solely for the software to communicate with *the user* — in a way natural to particular groups of users having different cultural preferences etc.  This certainly does not include interaction with database servers.  That is, locale settings might (and should) be used when you parse whatever your user entered to, say, a web form, but when you supply that data to a database backend, the data must be already normalized — in your case it *has to be* floaing-point numbers, not their string representations.  And use parameterized SQL queries, if applicable and possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for such descriptive answer. You indeed lead me to correct thought that it is somewhere overridden (although I didn't find where it is) and I ended up editing `~/.bashrc` with this: `export LC_ALL=lv_LV.UTF-8` and now when I write `$ locale` it shows correct one. About PHP part - yes, users locale shouldn't (and it isn't) affect communication with DB. And actually I had another problem with it but that's a new story. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should definitely read @kostix post.

Personally, I'm reconfiguring locales with `dpkg-reconfigure locales` on Debian.

For example:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ su -
[Password]

# dpkg-reconfigure locales
[Select C.UTF-8 for example]

# exit
$ su -
# locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did use `dpkg-reconfigure locales` also but it didn't change users locale instead as you show it affected only under `su` locale. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @SergeyZubov: it does set system-wide locale, however, there are numerous places where it may be overridden for specific user (in `~/.profile` for example).